# How to retrieve 1 table objects that is related to 2 ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I would like to show in my template in each cell the name ("nombre") of the client ("cliente") with his payment  `{{pago.cantidad_pagada}}` , the problem is that as I am doing it `{{presupuesto.cliente.nombre}}`, I show all the names that I have in my table and they are repeated in each of the cells, I imagine that it is due to the use of "for", but I don't know of another way to display the data.

> presupuestos.html

```
<tbody>
   {% for pago in pagos %}
   <tr>    
      <td>
         {% for presupuesto in presupuestos %}
         {{presupuesto.cliente.nombre}}
         {% endfor %}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{pago.cantidad_pagada}}
      </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor%}
</tbody>
```

> pagos/models.py

```
class Pagos(models.Model):
    numero_transaccion=models.IntegerField()
    estimate=models.ForeignKey(Presupuestos, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.numero_transaccion}'
```

> presupuestos/models.py

```
class Presupuestos(models.Model):
    cliente= models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cliente}'
```

> clientes/models.py

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
   
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nombre}'
```

> views.py

```
def presupuestosIndex(request):

    presupuestos = Presupuestos.objects.all()
    pagos=Pagos.objects.all()
    


    return render(request, "Presupuestos/presupuestos.html", {'presupuestos':presupuestos,'pagos':pagos})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key `estimate` from `Pagos` to `Presupuestos`. If that's the relationship you wish to display for each `pago` you would do

```
<tbody>
   {% for pago in pagos %}
   <tr>    
   <td>         
     {{pago.estimate.cliente.nombre}}
   </td>
   <td>
     {{pago.cantidad_pagada}} <! not in the models in the question -->
   </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor%}
</tbody>
```

Comment: It's strange, the following line didn't work either: {{pago.estimate.cliente.nombre}}. If I wrote {{pago.estimate}} it shows none. If i wrote {{pago.estimate.cliente}} appears blank and the same when I put {{pago.estimate.cliente.nombre}}

Comment: `pago.estimate == None` means that the related Foreignkey object was not specified (null) when the `pago` object was saved. So, you cannot follow the link. If that's a bug, it needs fixing.

Comment: ok but for example in the code of my question I see that if the names can be accessed but only by looping this----`{{presupuesto.customer.name}}`
(obviously it looks bad because all the names are in the same cell). So that problem is because of how my model is made?